# Prevent my flask app using html unicode for curly braces

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, flutterwave

I am making an API call in my flask app:

```
count = len(bankid)
bankid = "044"
response = requests.get(f"{base_api_url}/banks/" + "{bankid}/branches".format(bankid=f"{{{bankid}:0{count}d}}", headers=headers))
```

My target is to use this url `https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/banks/044/branches`. Passing in "044" string only removes the leading `zero` so trying to use python string formatting to pass in `{044:03d}`.

This is what I get:

```
GET /v3/banks/%7B044:03d%7D/branches HTTP/1.1" 401 65]
```

I want:

```
GET /v3/banks/044/branches HTTP/1.1" 401 65]
```

I want python to use "{}" rather than the unicode representation.

Comment: That's not "Unicode", or rather, all the characters in the URL and in your code are Unicode, but that's not at all the problem here.

Comment: btw, response code `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` may point out that initial problem could be in request parameters (`headers`), not `url`.

Comment: I have made that call when I hard code  the id and it returns the data but I want to pass it via request parameters in the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no point of having `bankId` a `string` and then tell fstring to treat it as `int` just to enforce formatting that would produce it back in the form of original string. You are simply over-complicating the way you construct target URL:

```py
bankid = "044"
response = requests.get(f"{base_api_url}/banks/{bankid}/branches", headers=headers)
```

---

EDIT

> The bankid has to be an int32 not string and when I pass it as into python strips the leading zero

Then you should have make it clear in your question first. Anyway, the change is trivial, just create string form of `bankId` as you like prior using it:

```py
bankid = 44
bankIdStr = str(bankId).zfill(3)  # change 3 to your liking
response = requests.get(f"{base_api_url}/banks/{bankidStr}/branches", headers=headers)
```

Comment: The bankid has to be an int32 not string and when I pass it as into python strips the leading zero

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I need an **int** not a **string** and the int should be able to have leading zeros

Comment: Seems you miss something fundamental here. `Int` is an `int`. There's a value of `int`. `Int` has a value. `Int` has no formatting. There's no leading zero in value of `int`. If you need leading zeros you need to format it as a string. This is why `bankIdStr` is introduced (imagine `bankId` is your function argument and you can happily typehint it as `int`. You can then put formatting directly into fstring, but it does not change the fact you need to format it.

Comment: Yes I just look at the api thought they want an int32 it didn't mean passing in a literal int32 but a string of that form

Comment: But if they said they want int32 then its nothing about leading zeros. You sure you need them?

Answer (score 0):

## Formatting

In terms of formatting, this should be enough for keeping any leading zeroes (in a string):

```py
some_string_id = '044'
url = f'{base_api_url}/banks/{some_string_id}/branches'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

## API reference

But from the API [perspective](https://developer.flutterwave.com/reference/endpoints/banks#get-bank-branches) it seems that what expected is `id` of a bank which is `integer`, not the `code` which is `string` and may as well have leading zeros. Make sure you pass an `id`. E.g.:

```py
# "id": 191,
# "code": "044",
# "name": "Access Bank"

bank_id = 191
url = f'{base_api_url}/banks/{bank_id}/branches'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: It strips the leading zero when I did it the way you are doing it

Comment: It does indeed. But why do you think you need them? I do not see any requirements of such kind in the documentation.

Comment: That's the bank id removing the leading zero produces an error as that id is none existent